# PPL H - Previously logged hours from the past towards CAA and EASA after Brexit

Tags: easa-regulations, ppl, logging, caa-uk-regulations

I have 50+ student hours in rotorcraft from about 8 years ago in the UK under the CAA.

I am now looking to restart training in Europe for a dual EASA and CAA license.

I've been told that because my previous training was 'incomplete' the previous 50 logbook hours I have are not able to be credited towards these license applications.

Looking at EASA Part-FCL (FCL.035) they just state that the hours must be logged in the appropriate type, and do not mention the location, authority or time these must have been completed in.
https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf

[image]

Is my interpretation correct that flight hours for an EASA PPL can be credited from any time period at any location?

Comment: Did you try to send an email to the Local CAA of the country you are restarting training in?

Comment: I have not but I will do that to check, in Europe it seem like the country itself is not always the country issuing the license. I'll check with the country that would most likely be issuing the license.

Comment: Yes the instruction can (could) be carried out with any EASA CFI. Check with the country you want the license issued from

Comment: No response from the Authority I want to register in, and none from the one I want to train in either. Seems no one in any position of deciding, doesn't want to handle this question.

Comment: did you try asking other flight schools?